# silverlight on mac oob

Tags: .net, macos, silverlight

I try to launch oob demo of microsoft silverlight and it hangs on 100% (on mac safari)

when i click on silverlight preferences it crashes with the following error:

what is the exact problem?

what should i do to make it happen?

very frustrated

```
Process:               Silverlight Preferences [589]
Path:                  /Library/Internet Plug-Ins/Silverlight.plugin/Contents/Resources/Silverlight Preferences.app/Contents/MacOS/Silverlight Preferences
Identifier:            com.microsoft.silverlight
Version:               5.1 (5.1.41212.0)
Code Type:             X86 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           Silverlight Preferences [589]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2016-02-09 10:52:42.364 +0200
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.10.5 (14F1605)
Report Version:        11
Anonymous UUID:        960F0D52-A8DD-366B-DEE3-F6642725E91D


Time Awake Since Boot: 950 seconds

Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000

Application Specific Information:
abort() called

Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x9b6cc69a __pthread_kill + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x91b0f634 pthread_kill + 101
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x92bdede2 abort + 156
3   com.microsoft.net.coreclr       0x07bb7294 0x7bac000 + 45716
4   com.microsoft.net.coreclr       0x07bb7318 0x7bac000 + 45848
5   com.microsoft.net.coreclr       0x07bb6dc8 0x7bac000 + 44488
6   com.microsoft.net.coreclr       0x07caf4e7 GetCLRRuntimeHost + 193895
7   com.microsoft.net.coreclr       0x07be2f13 PAL_InitializeCoreCLR + 58243
8   com.microsoft.net.coreclr       0x07cacccc GetCLRRuntimeHost + 183628
9   com.microsoft.net.coreclr       0x07cace05 GetCLRRuntimeHost + 183941
10  com.microsoft.net.coreclr       0x07cb2366 GetCLRRuntimeHost + 205798
11  com.microsoft.net.coreclr       0x07cb251b GetCLRRuntimeHost + 206235
12  com.microsoft.net.coreclr       0x07d74e7e GetCLRRuntimeHost + 1003262
13  com.microsoft.net.coreclr       0x07d759c5 GetCLRRuntimeHost + 1006149
14  com.microsoft.net.coreclr       0x07e25faa GetCLRRuntimeHost + 1728554
15  com.microsoft.net.coreclr       0x07ee5654 GetCLRRuntimeHost + 2512596
16  com.microsoft.silverlight       0x000050ac start + 5624
17  libobjc.A.dylib                 0x9bb5c5f0 -[NSObject performSelector:] + 62
18  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x9bf26a24 -[NSSet makeObjectsPerformSelector:] + 212
19  com.apple.AppKit                0x93cab216 -[NSIBObjectData nibInstantiateWithOwner:options:topLevelObjects:] + 1241
20  com.apple.AppKit                0x93caad37 -[NSIBObjectData nibInstantiateWithOwner:topLevelObjects:] + 56
21  com.apple.AppKit                0x93c87c31 loadNib + 462
22  com.apple.AppKit                0x93c86ff6 +[NSBundle(NSNibLoading) _loadNibFile:nameTable:options:withZone:ownerBundle:] + 330
23  com.apple.AppKit                0x93e4a0c5 +[NSBundle(NSNibLoadingInternal) _loadNibFile:externalNameTable:options:withZone:] + 161
24  com.apple.AppKit                0x93faddd7 +[NSBundle(NSNibLoading) loadNibFile:externalNameTable:withZone:] + 67
25  com.apple.AppKit                0x93c86c65 +[NSBundle(NSNibLoading) loadNibNamed:owner:] + 745
26  com.apple.AppKit                0x93c7ea30 NSApplicationMain + 690
27  com.microsoft.silverlight       0x00003baf start + 251
28  com.microsoft.silverlight       0x00003add start + 41

Thread 1:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x9b6cd8ce kevent64 + 10
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x9c3eece3 _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 245
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x9c3ee8c6 _dispatch_mgr_thread + 52

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x9b6cce6a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x91b0d72a _pthread_wqthread + 939
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x91b0ae0e start_wqthread + 30

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x9b6cce6a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x91b0d72a _pthread_wqthread + 939
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x91b0ae0e start_wqthread + 30

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x9b6cce6a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x91b0d72a _pthread_wqthread + 939
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x91b0ae0e start_wqthread + 30

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x9b6cce6a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x91b0d72a _pthread_wqthread + 939
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x91b0ae0e start_wqthread + 30

Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x9b6cce6a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x91b0d72a _pthread_wqthread + 939
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x91b0ae0e start_wqthread + 30

Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x9b6c69ce mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x9b6c5a70 mach_msg + 68
2   com.microsoft.net.coreclr       0x07bbacc2 0x7bac000 + 60610
3   com.microsoft.net.coreclr       0x07bb7de8 0x7bac000 + 48616
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x91b0dc25 _pthread_body + 138
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x91b0db9b _pthread_start + 162
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x91b0ae32 thread_start + 34

Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x9b6cd8b2 kevent + 10
1   com.microsoft.net.coreclr       0x07be94ee PAL_InitializeCoreCLR + 84318
2   com.microsoft.net.coreclr       0x07be9674 PAL_InitializeCoreCLR + 84708
3   com.microsoft.net.coreclr       0x07bedd67 PAL_InitializeCoreCLR + 102871
4   com.microsoft.net.coreclr       0x07be0d97 PAL_InitializeCoreCLR + 49671
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x91b0dc25 _pthread_body + 138
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x91b0db9b _pthread_start + 162
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x91b0ae32 thread_start + 34

Thread 9:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x9b6cc512 __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x91b0e1d7 _pthread_cond_wait + 842
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x91b0de88 pthread_cond_wait + 48
3   com.microsoft.net.coreclr       0x07be9dbd PAL_InitializeCoreCLR + 86573
4   com.microsoft.net.coreclr       0x07bee9b3 PAL_InitializeCoreCLR + 106019
5   com.microsoft.net.coreclr       0x07be8d57 PAL_InitializeCoreCLR + 82375
6   com.microsoft.net.coreclr       0x07be92a5 PAL_InitializeCoreCLR + 83733
7   com.microsoft.net.coreclr       0x07eda9c7 GetCLRRuntimeHost + 2468423
8   com.microsoft.net.coreclr       0x07be2f13 PAL_InitializeCoreCLR + 58243
9   com.microsoft.net.coreclr       0x07eda664 GetCLRRuntimeHost + 2467556
10  com.microsoft.net.coreclr       0x07cc43d4 GetCLRRuntimeHost + 279636
11  com.microsoft.net.coreclr       0x07cc5c56 GetCLRRuntimeHost + 285910
12  com.microsoft.net.coreclr       0x07d76035 GetCLRRuntimeHost + 1007797
13  com.microsoft.net.coreclr       0x07d760f1 GetCLRRuntimeHost + 1007985
14  com.microsoft.net.coreclr       0x07be2f13 PAL_InitializeCoreCLR + 58243
15  com.microsoft.net.coreclr       0x07d704e0 GetCLRRuntimeHost + 984416
16  com.microsoft.net.coreclr       0x07be2f13 PAL_InitializeCoreCLR + 58243
17  com.microsoft.net.coreclr       0x07d67ba3 GetCLRRuntimeHost + 949283
18  com.microsoft.net.coreclr       0x07d680a5 GetCLRRuntimeHost + 950565
19  com.microsoft.net.coreclr       0x07d680d4 GetCLRRuntimeHost + 950612
20  com.microsoft.net.coreclr       0x07cc606e GetCLRRuntimeHost + 286958
21  com.microsoft.net.coreclr       0x07d66b2e GetCLRRuntimeHost + 945070
22  com.microsoft.net.coreclr       0x07be0d97 PAL_InitializeCoreCLR + 49671
23  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x91b0dc25 _pthread_body + 138
24  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x91b0db9b _pthread_start + 162
25  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x91b0ae32 thread_start + 34

Thread 10:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x9b6cc512 __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x91b0e1d7 _pthread_cond_wait + 842
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x91b0f197 pthread_cond_timedwait + 47
3   com.microsoft.net.coreclr       0x07be9d96 PAL_InitializeCoreCLR + 86534
4   com.microsoft.net.coreclr       0x07bee9b3 PAL_InitializeCoreCLR + 106019
5   com.microsoft.net.coreclr       0x07be8d57 PAL_InitializeCoreCLR + 82375
6   com.microsoft.net.coreclr       0x07be92a5 PAL_InitializeCoreCLR + 83733
7   com.microsoft.net.coreclr       0x07eda9c7 GetCLRRuntimeHost + 2468423
8   com.microsoft.net.coreclr       0x07be2f13 PAL_InitializeCoreCLR + 58243
9   com.microsoft.net.coreclr       0x07eda664 GetCLRRuntimeHost + 2467556
10  com.microsoft.net.coreclr       0x07c19b23 MetaDataGetDispenser + 122259
11  com.microsoft.net.coreclr       0x07d66b2e GetCLRRuntimeHost + 945070
12  com.microsoft.net.coreclr       0x07be0d97 PAL_InitializeCoreCLR + 49671
13  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x91b0dc25 _pthread_body + 138
14  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x91b0db9b _pthread_start + 162
15  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x91b0ae32 thread_start + 34

Thread 0 crashed with X86 Thread State (32-bit):
  eax: 0x00000000  ebx: 0x07bb71e1  ecx: 0xbfffee9c  edx: 0x00000000
  edi: 0xa060c1d4  esi: 0x00000006  ebp: 0xbfffeeb8  esp: 0xbfffee9c
   ss: 0x00000023  efl: 0x00000206  eip: 0x9b6cc69a   cs: 0x0000000b
   ds: 0x00000023   es: 0x00000023   fs: 0x00000000   gs: 0x0000000f
  cr2: 0xa06daa00

Logical CPU:     0
Error Code:      0x00080148
Trap Number:     132



External Modification Summary:
  Calls made by other processes targeting this process:
    task_for_pid: 1
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0
  Calls made by this process:
    task_for_pid: 0
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0
  Calls made by all processes on this machine:
    task_for_pid: 470
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0

VM Region Summary:
ReadOnly portion of Libraries: Total=171.4M resident=34.7M(20%) swapped_out_or_unallocated=136.7M(80%)
Writable regions: Total=76.5M written=4088K(5%) resident=6216K(8%) swapped_out=0K(0%) unallocated=70.5M(92%)

REGION TYPE                      VIRTUAL
===========                      =======
CG image                              4K
CG shared images                    144K
CoreServices                        516K
Kernel Alloc Once                     4K
MALLOC                             45.4M
MALLOC (admin)                       64K
Memory Tag 242                       12K
Memory Tag 249                      156K
Stack                              68.6M
VM_ALLOCATE                        50.1M
__DATA                             8148K
__IMAGE                             528K
__IMPORT                             12K
__LINKEDIT                         41.7M
__OBJC                             2260K
__TEXT                            129.7M
__UNICODE                           552K
mapped file                       161.5M
shared memory                         4K
===========                      =======
TOTAL                             509.1M

Model: Macmini7,1, BootROM MM71.0220.B06, 2 processors, Intel Core i5, 1.4 GHz, 4 GB, SMC 2.24f32
Graphics: Intel HD Graphics 5000, Intel HD Graphics 5000, Built-In
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 2 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x80AD, 0x483943434E4E4E384A54414C41522D4E5444
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 2 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x80AD, 0x483943434E4E4E384A54414C41522D4E5444
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0x13B), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (7.15.166.24.3)
Bluetooth: Version 4.3.6f3 16238, 3 services, 27 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Wi-Fi, AirPort, en1
Serial ATA Device: APPLE HDD HTS545050A7E362, 500.11 GB
USB Device: IR Receiver
USB Device: BRCM20702 Hub
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
Thunderbolt Bus: Mac mini, Apple Inc., 26.1
```

Comment: First it is a dying technology. Do spend your time on something more useful such as JavaScript. Second, check Microsoft documentation to see if OOB is supported on OS X and Safari. Not everything works on Windows is guaranteed to work the same on OS X.

Comment: Possible solutions to your problem:  
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/981760  
https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6656667?start=0&tstart=0   
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1059424